# Sort groups in DataFrameGroupBy by size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame such as the following one:

```
    label   value
0   x       1
1   y       5
2   x       43
3   y       22
4   y       31
```

created by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['x', 1],['y', 5], ['x',43], ['y', 22], ['y', 31]], columns=['label', 'value'])
```

Now i want to group the data by label and iterate over the groups, which can be done as follows:

```
gdf = df.groupby('label')
for key, grp in gdf:
  print(key)
  # do stuff with grp
```

However, i want to iterate them in a specific order, the key being the size of the group.  In this case I would want to first process label `y` and its group as there are three records for the label and only after that label `x` as there are only two records.

All I manage to find so far is either "how to sort data within groups" or applying `.size().sort_values` to the `gdf`, which would achieve the desired sorting, but it effectively discards the underlying data (i.e., if I would do that I would be able access only the sizes of the groups, but not the actual, original data in the group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the groups before iterating:

```py
gdf = df.groupby("label")
for key, grp in sorted(gdf, key=lambda k: len(k[1]), reverse=True):
    print(key)
```

Prints:

```
y
x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the count and take the index i.e. label

```py
for i in gdf.count().sort_values('value', ascending=False).index:
    group = gdf.get_group(i)
    print(group)
```

```
   value
1      5
3     22
4     31
   value
0      1
2     43
```